# Conky doesn't show calendar on desktop

Tags: conky

I have configured conky and gcalcli to display a google calendar on my desktop.

My conky configuration file is the following:

```
conky.config = {
background = true,
update_interval = 1.5,
cpu_avg_samples = 2,
net_avg_samples = 2,
out_to_console = false,
override_utf8_locale = true,
double_buffer = true,
no_buffers = true,
text_buffer_size = 32768,
imlib_cache_size = 0,
own_window = true,
own_window_type = 'desktop',
own_window_argb_visual = true,
own_window_argb_value = 120,
own_window_hints = 'undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager',
border_inner_margin = 10,
border_outer_margin = 0,
xinerama_head = 1,
alignment = 'top_right',
gap_x = 90,
gap_y = 90,
draw_shades = true,
draw_outline = false,
draw_borders = false,
draw_graph_borders = false,
use_xft = true,
font = 'Ubuntu Mono:size=12',
xftalpha = 0.8,
uppercase = false,
default_color = '#FFFFFF',
own_window_colour = '#000000',
minimum_width = 0, minimum_height = 0,
};

conky.text = [[
    ${execpi 300 PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8 gcalcli --conky --nolineart calm --monday}
]];
```

When running the following line I get a sensible output:

```
gcalcli --conky --nolineart calm --monday

${color white}+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
${color white}|${color yellow}November 2018                                                               ${color white}|
${color white}+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
${color white}|${color yellow}Monday    ${color white}|${color yellow}Tuesday   ${color white}|${color yellow}Wednesday ${color white}|${color yellow}Thursday  ${color white}|${color yellow}Friday    ${color white}|${color yellow}Saturday  ${color white}|${color yellow}Sunday    ${color white}|
${color white}+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
${color white}|${color yellow}          ${color white}|${color yellow}          ${color white}|${color yellow}          ${color white}|${color yellow}01        ${color white}|${color yellow}02        ${color white}|${color yellow}03        ${color white}|${color yellow}04        ${color white}|
${color white}|          ${color white}|          ${color white}|          ${color white}|          ${color white}|          ${color white}|          ${color white}|          ${color white}|
${color white}|          ${color white}|          ${color white}|          ${color white}|${color magenta}12:00     ${color white}|${color green}Dragana   ${color white}|${color magenta}18:00     ${color white}|${color magenta}11:00     ${color white}|
${color white}|          ${color white}|          ${color white}|          ${color white}|${color magenta}Lunch     ${color white}|${color green}@Strangewa${color white}|${color magenta}Dinner    ${color white}|${color magenta}Brunch    ${color white}|
${color white}|          ${color white}|          ${color white}|          ${color white}|          ${color white}|${color green}ys        ${color white}|          ${color white}|          ${color white}|
${color white}|          ${color white}|          ${color white}|          ${color white}|${color magenta}18:00     ${color white}|          ${color white}|${color magenta}11:00     ${color white}|${color magenta}18:00     ${color white}|
${color white}|          ${color white}|          ${color white}|          ${color white}|${color magenta}Dinner    ${color white}|${color magenta}12:00     ${color white}|${color magenta}Brunch    ${color white}|${color magenta}Dinner    ${color white}|
${color white}|          ${color white}|          ${color white}|          ${color white}|          ${color white}|${color magenta}Lunch     ${color white}|          ${color white}|          ${color white}|
${color white}|          ${color white}|          ${color white}|          ${color white}|${color cyan}7:00am Go ${color white}|          ${color white}|${color cyan}11:30am   ${color white}|          ${color white}|
.......
```

I have also attached a screenshot of my desktop, the dark rectangle in the top right corner seems to be created by conky.

[image]